# how does calculate root mean square (rms) the sampling window?

Tags: python

I have the following scenario. I collected some acceleration data (accX, accY and accZ) from a three-phase motor through the Edge Impulse platform, using a smartphone.

When structuring my raw data in a Data frame, the following values are left:
[values of a sample collected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMEWV.jpg)

So plotting this data I have the following subplots:
[sampling subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWd1u.jpg)

So in this context, my difficulty in building a vector (list) that contains the rms root mean square of the samples comes into play.

I've been trying to calculate through the following code:

```
# calculate the average value of the accY column
media = dado['accY'].mean()

# calculate the RMS vector of the column
rms = np.sqrt(dado['accY'].apply(lambda x: (x - media)**2))
```

[result this code in plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnCfK.png) note: rms green line

My advisor said that rms and media should have the following behavior inside the accY subplot:
[red rms and green media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLxRl.jpg)
Note: rms red line and medium green line.

### So what are your opinions, is it wrong in the code?

New implementations, I've been developing moving rms of accelerations:

```
rms = (pd.DataFrame(abs(dado['accX'].values)**2).rolling(window).mean()) **0.5
```

[image: moving rms]

that makes sense?

---

Comment: your advisor maybe using a fixed size window to calculate RMS

Comment: Yes, he confirmed it to me just now. Could you suggest something (reference) on how to implement?

Comment: I think you are not calculating RMSE but instead calculating Standard Deviation.

Comment: The link you've provided is behind a login screen to a community people might not always have access to. Do you mind writing an answer below with the relevant details?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi of course, I'll edit

Comment: @Renan I meant add it as an answer below (in the "Answer" box, then click "Post your answer" instead of editing it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I managed to solve it by**

Here n is window of size n and let’s say you have an array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and window of size n = 2, then to calculate moving RMS for each window (x_i) or element in the array, you should have to compute the sum of squares of x_i and n-1 right shifted values (1 right shifted value in this case) in the array.

For example,

```
moving RMS = √( 1/n Σ x_i^2 ), where i = i to i+n-1,

moving RMS for window 1 = np.sqrt((1/2) * np.sum([1^2, 2^2])) = 1.58

moving RMS for window 2 = np.sqrt((1/2) * np.sum([2^2, 3^2])) = 2.54

moving RMS for window 3 = np.sqrt((1/2) * np.sum([3^2, 4^2])) = 3.53

moving RMS for window 4 = np.sqrt((1/2) * np.sum([4^2, 5^2])) = 4.52

moving RMS for window 5 can not be calculated.
```

Use code below:

```
for i in range(len(dado['accX'])):
  rms[i] = (i+window-1 < len(dado['accX'])) * np.sqrt( (1/window) * np.sum( dado['accX'].loc[i:i+window-1]**2 ) )
```

[![moving rms][3]][3]

Answer (score 1):

RMSE is defined for two sets of values, Here you are using a single set of 'accY' to calculate RMSE? This is not possible what you are doing is calculating the Standard Deviation, the deviation from the mean value. Here is a sample dataset which implements standard deviations.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.randint(low = 0,high=1000,size=100),'col2':np.random.randint(low = 0,high=120,size=100)})
aa = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='4/10/2018')
df.index = aa
df['std'] = df.rolling('5D')['col1'].std()
df = df.fillna(0)
plt.plot(df.index.values, df.col1.values)
plt.plot(df.index.values, df['std'].values)
```

I have created a window of 5 days calculated the standard deviation for those 5 days and plotted it against the original values.

Comment: I am not understanding the meanings of the words for this case. What I mean to say
he would be?
rms[i] = sqrt (sum (data['accX'].rolling(window) - mean(data['accX'])/len(data['accX']))

Comment: do you know what is RMS? Go read about it first